# ImportError: cannot import name Person

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I'm a beginner with python so tell me if I'm missing out on something.
I have a python file named abc.py that looks like this:

```py
class Person: 
    def __init__ (self, age, weight, height, first_name, last_name, gpa ):
        self.age = age
        self.weight = weight
        self.height = height
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.gpa = gpa 



def on_honor_roll(self):
    if self.gpa >= 3.5:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

And another python file named objetc_functions.py that looks like this:
from abc import Person

```py
user1 = Person(25, 80, 178, "John", "Williams", "To be or not to be") 
user2 = Person(15, 78, 190, "Joe", "James", "Good morning" )

print(user1.on_honor_roll())
```

And when I run objectfunctions I get an InportError message that says:
`ImportError: cannot import name "Person" from "abc"`

Comment: `on_honor_roll` isn't indented to be part of the Person class for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) is a Python core module. You should avoid naming your modules like core modules.

Comment: Changed the name to another thing and it still shows the ImportError message.

Comment: There might be `.pyc` files or `__pycache__` which you need to delete. Also, did you adjust the import statement?

Comment: How do I delet them?

Comment: That depends on your operating system. On mine, I open a file explorer, select the keys/folders I want to delete and press the `Delete` key.

Comment: Do I delete the entire _pycache_ folder?

Comment: Yes, you can savely delete it

Comment: Thank you. After hours it finnaly work. Thank you so much :)

Comment: I'm happy I could help :-) I know every start can be super frustrating - but it gets better quickly with Python. Just keep going 

Comment: If this answer solved your issue, please accept it